# turn off the P symbol in my code in Coda 2

Tags: php, coda

Can someone help he figure out how to turn off these P symbols in my PHP code in Coda 2?

[image: Text]

Thank you!!

Comment: Did you try Preferences...Editor...Show invisible characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are line endings. You can change your settings or convert your files in the Text => Line endings menu

Comment: Does that just convert the line ending or does it also hide the line ending symbol in the editor?